# Pass input event from one element to another element

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to clone an input field and redirect the input of the original input field to the clone. My current solution looks like this, but nothing happens on the clone:

```js
var original = document.getElementById("input1")
var clone = original.cloneNode(true)
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD'
})

clone.id += '-clone'
original.parentElement.append(clone)
original.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
clone.dispatchEvent(new event.constructor(event.type, event))
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
})

original.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    original.value = formatter.format(clone.value)
})
```

```html
<input id="input1" />
```

If I add an event listener to the clone for an keypress-event, it gets triggered successfully but the value stays empty.
What is the missing part to change the clone value?

EDIT: The appropriate example can be seen on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jonasesr/pen/KKKNjpr).

EDIT 2: The reason why I cannot pass the value to the clone is, that I need to format the input field value but also need the raw input. Therefore `clone.value = event.target.value;` is no solution.

**TL;DR**: I need the formatted value in the original input field and the original value in the cloned field.

Comment: your not setting the value in the inputfield. clone.value = original.value; and remove event.preventDefault() from the function.

Comment: You are sending an event from original input, but clone does not have a listener.
`clone.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
 clone.value += event.key;
});`

Comment: I see in the comments that your question is pretty unclear at the moment. So explain yourself more in the question what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please excuse me on this. I need the formatted value in the original input field and the original value in the cloned field.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but I added

clone.value = original.value;

and changed keypress to keyup.

```js
var original = document.getElementById("input1");
var clone = original.cloneNode(true);

clone.id += '-clone';
original.parentElement.append(clone);

original.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {

  clone.value = original.value; // This what you are looking for?
  
  clone.dispatchEvent(new event.constructor(event.type, event));

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
#input1 {
  background: orange;
}

#input1-clone {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" />
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is looking for, in his example, calling `.preventDefault()` on the `keypress` event leaves the original input empty.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I calll `.preventDefault()` to set the value to a formatted string later manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to redirect the input you can try this. This solution is listening to `input` event and setting it to the cloned element.

```js
var original = document.getElementById("input1")
var clone = original.cloneNode(true)
clone.id += '-clone'
original.parentElement.append(clone)

original.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    clone.value = event.target.value
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input id="input1"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's right, but I need to transform the input value after an input. Therefore I cannot use this solution.

Comment: @Jonas If you want to do that then you can do it in the listener function. Could you explain more clearly what you want to do?

Comment: I already amended the question. To sum up, I have 2 Input fields. I need the formatted value in the original input field and the original value in the cloned field

Answer (score 0):

It seems the OP needs to format currency input as the user types and keep a copy of the raw data.

So we need to somehow hide the input the user is actually typing in and show the formatted input instead.

The correct event to use for redirecting input is.... on`input`.

Showing a caret on the formatted input is tricky but I'll try and edit the answer to address this problem.

Below a (kind of) working example:

```js
var original = document.getElementById("input1");
var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
clone.id += '-clone';
original.parentElement.parentElement.append(clone);
var formattedClone = original.cloneNode(true);
formattedClone.id += '-formatted-clone';
original.parentElement.insertBefore(formattedClone, original);

original.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  const currency = 'GBP';
  const locale = 'en-GB';
  // const formattedValue = event.target.value;
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, { style: 'currency', currency: currency });
  // const raw = formatToRaw(formattedValue, formatter);
  original.value = event.target.value;
  formattedClone.value = formatter.format(event.target.value);
  clone.value = event.target.value;
});
```

```css
#input1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"><input id="input1" /></div>
```

Comment: That's right to simply sync the values, but I need to transform the input value after an input. Therefore there will be a difference between both values and I cannot use this solution.

Comment: The format will be a currency. The process looks like this:

`const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: currency
      })

   original.value = formatter.format(clone.value)
`

Comment: I think I get it, you need the formatted value in the original input field and the original value in the cloned field? right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly! The user should have the feeling, that he inputs a money value.

Comment: I'm working on a solution to show the caret but aside that, this is a working solution

Comment: Very interesting solution. Unfortunately the solution seems confusing from the user's point of view.